# Convert array of string to array of Json objects in Postgresql Jsonb

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

i have a jsonb column like

```
{
    "foo":{"bar" :["b","c","d"]}
}
```

Which I want to convert all items of "bar" array to a json with a "name" key result shall be:

```
{
    "foo":{"bar" :[{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"d"}]}
}
```

I wish to do it using postgresql queries in all rows of my table.

I tried various queries and functions but my main issue is at wrapping part of my strings.

Tips and helps are appriciated

Comment: `["name":"b","name":"c","name":"d"]` is invalid because it is not an object notation. Also same keys in the object is not allowed

Comment: Are you actually using `Postgres 9.1`?  It looks like native `JSON` support wasn't added until 9.2 and `JSONB` wasn't added until 9.4.

Comment: And `jsonb` wasn't added until 9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using a version of Postgres with JSON support (9.4+), this should get you close:

```sql
WITH cte(myJSON) AS (
  SELECT CAST('{"foo":{"bar" :["b","c","d"]}}'AS JSONB) AS MyJSON 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT CAST('{"foo":{"bar" :["e","f","g"]}}'AS JSONB) AS MyJSON  
) 

SELECT
  JSON_AGG(
    (SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(_) FROM (SELECT name) AS _)
  ) myrow
FROM (
  SELECT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(myjson->'foo'->'bar') AS name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS RowNum
  FROM cte
) src
GROUP BY src.RowNum
```

This will return `[{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"d"}]`.

You can then construct your final `JSON` as needed.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/37565)
[Reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27732/set-names-to-attributes-when-creating-json-with-row-to-json)

**Update**
This is very hacky and I'm sure there's a cleaner way, but I updated the query above to handle multiple rows.  Just replace the `CTE` references with your actual table name and `myjson` with the name of your `JSON` column.

Output:

```
[{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"d"}]
[{"name":"e"},{"name":"f"},{"name":"g"}]
```

Let me know if that works.

**Updated Update**
Here's an `UPDATE` statement you can use:

```sql
UPDATE t1 tgt
SET jsoncol = JSONB_SET(
  jsoncol, -- Source JSON
  '{foo,bar}', -- Target node to update
  src.new_json -- New value 
)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ID, 
    JSONB_AGG(
      (SELECT TO_JSONB(_) FROM (SELECT name) AS _) -- Convert new row to JSON
    ) new_json
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      ID, 
      JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(jsoncol->'foo'->'bar') AS name -- Convert array to rows
    FROM t1
  ) src
  GROUP BY src.ID
) src
WHERE tgt.ID = src.ID -- Update "tgt" table with rows from "src" table
;
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vbphsVsLh3r5tfAvLVZQuS/0)

Comment: It works only for a single row, any idea how can I loop over all rows ?

Comment: It works charm, but now I face another issue, I am updating this table which only bar supposed to change ,  any clue on how to write the update ?

Comment: You can use something like this: `UPDATE MyTable SET jsoncol = JSONB_SET(jsoncol, '{foo,bar}', <new_JSON_value>)`.  This will replace the value in `foo->bar` with `new_JSON_value`.  If you want to use the query above you'll need to do an `UPDATE FROM` and join the "src" table to the "tgt" table.  What is the `PK` of the table you want to update?

Comment: It has an ID as primary key. I tried your approach but it is copying all rows

Comment: what do you mean by "tgt" table ?

Comment: "tgt" = target table, "src" = source table.  See above.  Let me know if it works